# SSIS return values from multiple procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis

I am trying to return values from multiple stored procedures that are being run within an Execute SQL task but it appears that only the result set of the first procedure call.  Essentially what I'm doing is this:

```
DECLARE @input INT,
        @input2 INT,
        @output INT,
        @output2 INT


EXEC dbo.SomeProcedure @input, @output OUTPUT
EXEC dbo.SomeProcedure @input2 @output2 OUTPUT

SELECT @output AS Output1,
        @output2 AS Output2
```

Is there a way to run multiple procedures in an Exec SQL Task, assign values to local SQL variables and then return the values of those variables to SSIS?

Comment: I would've thought that would work. You're returning one resultset with two columns. Do you have `SET NOCOUNT ON` in your procs? Does just one proc work? Break it down until you find the issue

Answer (score 3):

The Execute SQL Task cannot handle multiple result sets.   If you must handle multiple result sets in a single task, one way is to use a Script Task.   [This article](https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2015/04/27/the-ssis-object-variable-and-multiple-result-sets/) has more detail and sample code.

However to do what you describe in your question, you don't HAVE to do it in a single task, and your package will be much easier to read and maintain if you simply use two Execute SQL Tasks.

A third option, if you have permission to create stored procedures, is to write a single wrapper procedure that calls the other procedures and combines their results to a single result as needed.